# Анимация селектора меню при скролле

Tags: jquery, анимация, прокрутка

Имеется простая разметка в виде менюшки, div'ов, на которые пункты менюшки ссылаются и небольшого stick'а, который должен двигаться под менюшкой в зависимости от того, на каком блоке контента пользователь находится.

Также имеется js - код, который делает нужный пункт менюшки активный при скролле и при нажатии, а также делает шапку фиксированной при определенном скролле от top'a

```js
$(window).on('scroll', (function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 299) {
    $('.navigation').addClass("navigation-fixed");
    $('#block1').css("margin-top", "50px");
    $('.navigation-pos').addClass("navigation-pos-animate");
    $('.fa-home').addClass('fa-home-visible');
    $('.nav-button-selected').addClass('nav-button-selected-visible');
    $('.inner-navigation-pos').addClass('inner-navigation-pos-animate');
  } else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass("navigation-fixed");
    $('#block1').css("margin-top", "0px");
    $('.navigation-pos').removeClass("navigation-pos-animate");
    $('.fa-home').removeClass('fa-home-visible');
    $('.nav-button-selected').removeClass('nav-button-selected-visible');
    $('.inner-navigation-pos').removeClass('inner-navigation-pos-animate');
  }
}));

$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$('.navigation-pos').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(document).off("scroll");
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 50
  }, 800, function() {
    window.location.hash = target;
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
  });
});

function onScroll() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('.inner-nav a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top - 50 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('.inner-nav a').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner-navigation-pos">
  <ul class="inner-nav">
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#block1">About me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#block2">My works</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#block3">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#block4">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="nav-button-selected"></div>
</div>
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
<div id="block3"></div>
<div id="block4"></div>
```

Задача - заставить stick под менюшкой двигаться в зависимости от того, на каком блоке контента я нахожусь. То - есть, я начинаю с первого блока, скроллю, и как только я налезаю на второй блок, палочка передвигается под второй пункт меню. Если что - либо не понятно, то подробнее на все это дело можно поглядеть [здесь](http://user423.bslhostfd.ru/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вы определили какой элемент активный и назначили ему класс:

```
currLink.addClass("active");
```

Далее определяете его позицию с помощью [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
var left=currLink.position().left;
```

затем ширину с помощью [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
var width=currLink.width();
```

И даете эти координаты вашей полосочке. (Она должна быть `position:absolute`, а само меню - `position:relative`). Анимацию задаете с помощью [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$( "#id_полосочки" ).animate({
    width: width+'px',
    left: left+'px'
  },300);
```

[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) надо вызывать только при смене активного блока, иначе анимация будет сбиваться при постоянной прокрутке. Создайте **глобальную**(!) переменную, которая будет содержать последний активный блок:

```
 var lastactive;
```

и вызывайте `animate` только при изменении актиного блока.

```
 if(lastactive!=currLink.attr('href')){
       lastactive=currLink.attr('href');
       $( "#id_полосочки" ).animate(
            .....
       );
 }
```

Comment: вроде получилось, но корректо работает только когда переходишь на блоки по ссылке, а если просто скроллить - работает, но странно. ( неправильно работает speed у animate, еще есть косяки, но я не знаю, как их описать словами - посмотрите по ссылке сверху пж)

Comment: @g3rmesov А все ясно,когда скролишь, `animate` постоянно вызывается и не дает анимации происходить нормально. Сейчас допишу в ответ

Comment: воо, спасибо большое, все заработало) можно еще вопросец по скроллу? между блоком my works и blog как - будто есть какое - то пустое пространство, когда класс active не срабатывает, между blog и contacts тоже. голову сломал, не пойму, в чем дело, не подскажите?) (можно увидеть это на медленном скролле или просто перейти по ссылке blog или contacts)